# plot more than 50 components in RSSA package in R

Tags: r, svd

```
require(Rssa)
t=ssa(co2,200) #200 here should be the number of components
plot(t)       # this way it plots only the first 50 not 200!
```

Above code produces a graph the first 50 components only. I need to plot more than 50 components

I tried

```
plot(t$sigma[1:200],type='l',log='y')
```

but it didn't work!

Example : similar to this case
[accessing eigenvalues in RSSA package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013393/accessing-eigenvalues-in-rssa-package-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the help page for `?ssa` we see a parameter named `neig` which is documented as;

> integer, number of desired eigentriples. If 'NULL', then sane default value will be used, see 'Details'

Using that as a named parameter:

```
 t=ssa(co2, neig=200) 
 plot(t)
```

[image]

And:

```
> t$sigma
  [1] 78886.190749   329.031810   327.198387   184.659743    88.695271    88.191805    52.380502
  [8]    40.527875    31.329930    29.409384    27.157698    22.334446    17.237926    14.175096
 [15]    14.111402    12.976716    12.943775    12.216524    11.830642    11.614243    11.226010
 [22]    10.457529    10.435998  snipped the remaining 200 numbers.
```

(Apparently, the package authors do not consider 200 to be "sane" number to use, although looking at the values of the results from neig=50 and neig-200 I do not see a discernable cutpoint at the 50th eigenvalue. But ... they must set it in the code which I've shown you how to access.)

Comment: Thank you very much! you are amazing sir.